# Why typescript allows cast anonymous type to object even if the type does not match the object props

Tags: angular, typescript, casting

In my typescript code, I need to update just one property of my class with new value.

```
export class ValidationState {
  isLabourComponentValid: boolean = true;
  isTableValid: boolean = true;
  isFaultCausingPartValid: boolean = true;


  public mergeValues(newValue: ValidationState){
    Object.assign(this, newValue);
    return this;
  }
}
```

The usage is: I send just one property to the merge function, I cast the property, to match the required type, even, if it is not that type, but typescript let me to do it.

```
  ValidationState.mergeValues({isLabourComponentValid: false} as ValidationState);
  ValidationState.mergeValues({isTableValid: false} as ValidationState);
```

The result is, that the Validation class is correctly updated and the new class values are:  {false, false, true}.
Everything is working perfectly, I can extend the class with new property and its get updated by the merge function, I dont need to care about further merging. How ever, is this good approach? 
Other approach is to manually update property by property, which will be also type safe.

Comment: I allows it because *casting* is done to bypass a type system in some extent. This is done by a programmer to tell a compiler to treat a given value as a different type despite what the compiler thinks. It's inherently unsafe, yes, but it bypasses situations where the programmer *does* know that, say, `Array<Animal>` actually only `Cat` objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works fine, but a cleaner approach would be to accept a [`Partial<ValidationState>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialt) as argument of `mergeValues()`. You wouldn't need a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) (which is just a way to tell the compiler: trust me, I know what I'm doing) anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of casting, you can have the parameter of your `mergeValues` function be a `Partial<ValidationState>`.

When you cast, you are telling TypeScript to blindly trust that what you're sending in is correct. Using a `Partial` will give you a bit more type safety, since TypeScript will then at least check that what is being passed in is a subset of `ValidationState`.